# Python Requests on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-requests

Ive used pip to install requests but when i run my scrpit i get an import error.

I have also tried installing from github but still same issue.

Here is output

```
Successfully uninstalled requests-2.18.4
osx:shane shane$ sudo -H pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.18.4
osx:shane shane$ python scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

what am i doing wrong ?

sys.path output

print sys.path

```
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg']
```

Comment: Print the `import sys; sys.base_prefix` and `sys.path` and see if you are using the same python you've installed `requests` into. The `pip` looks like a `brew` version the second maybe the system version.

Comment: `pip` is installing `requests` in a different instance of python. Update your environment. `which pip`, `which python`, change your path. Look into virtual environments (`virtualenv`) it will massively simplify things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `python -m pip install requests` to install requests.

This downloads `requests` to the same python that is run on the shell.

Comment: Its always something so simple